# Detect ToolTip on row of RadGrid using WebAii

Tags: c#, radgrid, telerik-grid, webaii

We use a tooltip on our RadGrid to present a feedback message to a user when a row is disabled.  During a test, is there any way to detect what the text of the tooltip is when hovering over a particular row by using  the WebAii suite?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that the <tr> element of the rows that have tooltips have their title attribute set.  Is this the best/standard way to detect tooltips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the title attribute is how tooltips are added to elements in HTML. See here for more information. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp. Do you need assistance reading the title attribute with the WebAii framework?

Cody Gibson
Telerik Technical Support